# Slowly fill SVG progress bar with color using tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I created a progressbar using svg with tailwind css and it works fine, but how can I make the fill slow? Is this possible using tailwind or css?

```js
let circumference = 50 * 2 * Math.PI;

  <div className="flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden rounded-full">
    <svg
      className="w-28 h-28 transform translate-x-1 translate-y-1"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <circle
        className="text-gray-200"
        strokeWidth="15"
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="transparent"
        r="40"
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
      />
      <circle
        className="text-red-600"
        strokeWidth="15"
        strokeDasharray={circumference}
        strokeDashoffset={`calc(${circumference} - (${circumference} * ${progressPercentage}) / 100)`}
        strokeLinecap="round"
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="transparent"
        r="40"
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
      />
    </svg>
    <span className="absolute text-blue-700">{progressPercentage}%</span>
  </div>
```

thank you